# Synchronous ConnectionRequest for codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

Is it possible to do a synchronous `ConnectionRequest` in codenameone? I mean something like

```
Result result = NetworkManager.getInstance().invokeAndWait(myRequest);
```

with `Result` containing the response `InputStream` (and ideally also the response headers).

---

The reason for this requirement is my experience with an asynchronous code doing what I want to do, where the asynchrony makes it extremely hard to understand (even though I'm rather used to it). Another reason is that there's nothing to gain from asynchrony as there's a single peer to talk to and the whole communication must be strictly sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See `addToQueueAndWait` both in the `CN` class and `NetworkConnection`.

You can also use similar options in the `Rest` class which provides shorthand for common network calls.

Comment: I see, I was blind. I can override `readResponse` and store the input, but what about the headers? There's `getResponseCode` and `getResponseContentType`, that's fine, but all header methods need a `connection`....

Comment: You override read headers too and the connection is passed to that object. Notice that for most use cases (e.g. auth headers) `Rest` has pre-made features that simplify that